# Page_Load not really firing during event function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I hard code `Page_Load(sender, e)` in event function `btn_RouteMatrix`. Codes are as follows.

``UpdateRouteMatrix function will take pretty long time, so I want to load a waiting info during it's running.
After changing the attribute like this:

```
this.form1.Visible = false;
this.imgLoad.Visible = true;
```

I hard code Page_Load(sender, e) in event function `btn_RouteMatrix`, But Page_Load doesn't really firing during the event function, because the page doesn't change at all. The confusing part is when I debug it, `Page_Load` is indeed called.

So what is the problem about this situation, is it feasible to work this way.

```
protected void btn_RouteMatrix(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    // DAL method
    int n = ...
    int m = ...

    if (n==m)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(ClientScript.GetType(), "myscript", "<script>dialogmodal('All the data already exist');</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        // showing the waiting information instead of the form
        this.form1.Visible = false;
        this.imgLoad.Visible = true;
        Page_Load(sender, e);

        // this method takes pretty long time
        DistancetimematrixBusiness.UpdateRouteMatrix(this.LoginOrganizationId, this.LoginUserID);

        var msg = "Success";

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(ClientScript.GetType(), "myscript", "<script>dialogmodal('" + msg + "');</script>");
    }

    // change the visible attribute, showing data in form instead of waiting info
    this.form1.Visible = true;
    this.imgLoad.Visible = false;

    BindData();            
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but Page_Load is actually being called before the event handlers for controls.

[MSDN .NET Page lify cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I want to show loading info right from that point. So I change the attributes about "visible". It is all form data showing before that.

Comment: You should properly do that in the more appropite events as the LifeCycle is (simplified) Page_Load -> EventHandling -> PreRender... so perhaps PreRender is more something usable for you here.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't call event handlers manually. If you need to perform similar or same actions as, say in Page_Load, just do something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoStuff();
}

protected void btn_RouteMatrix(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    DoStuff();
}

private void DoStuff()
{
    // put your loading, displaying and other code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Server side events are all executed prior any response is sent to the client, so in your case the form and the image will be toggled then un-toggled before the response is sent.

To get your intended behavior, you should toggle the visibility client side on form submit (using javascript), when the server response returns, the whole page will be updated.

Or you may switch to using '[UpatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386454%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)'  along with '[UpdateProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398821%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)' controls.